# how to solve this error while connecting Github repository to Heroku

Tags: reactjs, github, heroku

Can anyone please help my issue

[this is an error copy which I got when trying to connect GitHub repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u31gZ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if this is similar to [heroku/heroku-buildpack-go issue 8](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-go/issues/8)

```
heroku config:unset BUILDPACK_URL; 
heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt.git
```

(replace the URL by the one reported in your error message)

Read also "[Using Multiple Buildpacks for an App](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app)" to check the status of your buildpacks in your Heroku application.